# bootstrap-vue modal not displaying

Tags: vue.js, .net-core, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

#### environment

```
dotnet core 2.1.0

"bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
"nuxt": "^1.4.1",
"vue": "^2.5.16",
"vue-axios": "^2.1.1",
"vue-router": "^3.0.1",
"vue-server-renderer": "^2.1.8",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16",
"vue-toasted": "^1.1.24",
"vuex": "^3.0.1",
"vuex-router-sync": "^4.0.1"
```

I can't figure out how to get a simple bootstrap-vue modal working. The `modal-sample` component renders, with the button visible, but when the button is clicked nothing happens (modal doesn't "show").

However, in the vue dev tools, I can see the `show` event was emitted. Also, if I copy and paste the code in the bootstrap-vue playground it works, so it has to be my set up. Not sure if it matters but it's also running in a dotnet core environment.

#### webpack.config

```
  const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');

  ...

  resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue',
           ...
        }
        ...
        ,
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.vue$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'vue-loader' },
            { test: /\.js$/, 
                include: [/ClientApp/, 
                require.resolve("bootstrap-vue")], 
                use: 'babel-loader' },
            { test: /\.css$/, 
                use: isDevBuild ? ['vue-style-loader', 'style-loader', 'css-loader'] : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: 'css-loader' }) },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, 
                use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
        // Plugins that apply in development builds only
        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
            filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
            moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
        })
    ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new ExtractTextPlugin({use: 'site.css', fallback: 'vue-style-loader'})
        ])
}];
```

#### app-root.vue

```
  import Swapshift from './modal-sample'
  Vue.component('modal-sample', Swapshift);
```

#### modal-sample.vue

```
 <template>
    <div style="margin-top: 20px; padding: 10px;">
      <b-button variant="primary" v-b-modal.newSwapShiftModal>New Swap Shift</b-button>
      <b-modal id="newSwapShiftModal" title="New Swap Edit" >
        <div class="d-block text-center">
            <h3>Hello From My Modal!</h3>
        </div>
      </b-modal>
    </div>
 </template>

 <script>
   import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex'
   import bModal from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/modal/modal'
   import bModalDirective from 'bootstrap-vue/es/directives/modal/modal' 

 export default {
    components: { bModal },
    directives: { bModalDirective },
    data() {
       return {
          swapshift: {
            id: 1,
            status: {
                id: 1,
                description: 'Requested'
            }
          }
        }
    },
    computed: {   
    },
    methods: {
    },
    async created() {
       console.log('...in modal-sample1');
    }
  }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML attributes all get translated to `lowercase`.  This includes parts of the directive attribute on your button.  So what is happening is that when the v-b-modal directive receives the modifiers (ie. `.newSwapShiftModal`), it receives `newswapshiftsodal` from the browser (**all** attributes are always lowercased by the browser).

So you need to set the `id` on the modal to also be lowercase (as attribute values inside quotes retain their case).

```html
 <template>
    <div style="margin-top: 20px; padding: 10px;">
      <b-button variant="primary" v-b-modal.new-swap-shift-modal>New Swap Shift</b-button>
      <b-modal id="new-swap-shift-modal" title="New Swap Edit" >
        <div class="d-block text-center">
            <h3>Hello From My Modal!</h3>
        </div>
      </b-modal>
    </div>
 </template>
```

Example fiddle showing case sensitivity issues with IDs: https://jsfiddle.net/4cnk28yw/

EDIT: also register the directive with the correct name (as mentioned by @ittus):

```js
import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex'
import { BModal, VBModal } from 'bootstrap-vue'

export default {
  components: { BModal },
  directives: { 'b-modal': VBModal },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: `.thisIs` camel case, Vue actually converts to `.this-is` which is called kebab case.

Comment: yes, blah-blah is called kebab case.... I was just using it as an example... it just needs to be lower case characters (i could have used no `-` chars or `_` instead). Vue does not auto convert to kebab case for directive modifiers/args, and not when using in-browser templates (the browser parses the HTML first before Vue, translating **all attributes* to lowercase)

Answer (score 1):

Directive name should be `b-modal`. You should try changing:

```
directives: { 
  'b-modal': bModalDirective 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ittus for the suggestion but that didn't work